# R function to define several factor levels as missing

Tags: r, function

I have several factors with levels "No answer" and "don't know" which I want to define as missing. However, the function I wrote to achieve this is not working and I cannot figure out why.
Example:

```
y <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "Don´t know", "No answer"))
z <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "Don´t know", "No answer"))
y

[1] a          b          c          Don´t know No answer 
Levels: a b c Don´t know No answer
```

Defining levels as missing for a single variable does work

```
levels(y)[levels(y)=="Don´t know"|levels(y)=="No answer"]<- NA
y
[1] a    b    c    <NA> <NA>
Levels: a b c
```

However, applying a function does not.

```
nafac <- function(x)
{
levels(x)[levels(x)=="Don´t know"|levels(x)=="No answer"]<- NA
}
nafac(z)
z
[1] a          b          c          Don´t know No answer 
Levels: a b c Don´t know No answer
```

What is the problem with the function? Thank you!

Comment: Your function modified its local copy; it needs to return the modified value, and you call it as `z <- nafac(z)`.

Comment: R passes by *value* rather than by reference.  So as [@user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2554330) said: all `nafac(z)` does is store the *value* of `z` within `x`, and then modify `x` *within* the scope of the function. The original `z` is left unchanged in your workspace. What you need to do is rewrite `nafac()` to `return()` the modified version of `x`, and then use this result to overwrite the original `z` like so: `z <- nafac(z)`.

Answer (score 1):

we can simply add `return` to return updated vector;

```
nafac <- function(x){
levels(x)[levels(x)=="Don´t know"|levels(x)=="No answer"]<- NA
return(x)
}

nafac(z)
```

output;

```
a b c <NA> <NA>
```